# I would be grateful if someone would respond

Tags: grammar

Is both correct
Vote for 2 favorite cars or
Vote for the 2 favorite cars 
I want to know what is correctly

Answer (score 1):

Vote for **your** two favorite cars

favorite is a subjective thing, so you need to specify who's favorite it is.